# Python pandas dataframe reshape long to wide, multiple columns and constant values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

I need to reshape a DataFrame from long to wide format. Example of what the data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 'id_age':
30,30,30,23,23,23,29,29], 'product':['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B'],
'rank':[1,2,3,3,1,2,2,1], 'result':['x','y','z','p','q','r','s','t']})

print(df)

   id  id_age product  rank result
0   1      30       A     1      x
1   1      30       B     2      y
2   1      30       C     3      z
3   2      23       A     3      p
4   2      23       B     1      q
5   2      23       C     2      r
6   3      29       A     2      s
7   3      29       B     1      t
```

The desired output is

```
id  id_age    product       rank     result
0   1      30  [A, B, C]  [1, 2, 3]  [x, y, z]
1   2      23  [A, B, C]  [3, 1, 2]  [p, q, r]
2   3      29     [A, B]     [2, 1]     [s, t]
```

i.e. one row per id. I have tried to solve the problem by creating a pivot table, but I cannot figure out how to:

1. reshape it for more than one column (product, rank, result)
2. handle the values that are constant within individuals (id_age)
3. get the columns in the final data frame to be in list format (and the order is important, the first value of the list in rank corresponds to the first value of the list in result for a given individual).

Any recommendations on how to move forward on this issue is appreciated!

Comment: As a reminder, pandas really doesn't support putting nonscalar entries in cells.  Unless this is the very last step in your process, you're likely to encounter some mysterious behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working:

```
df = df.groupby(['id','id_age']).agg(tuple).applymap(list)
print (df)
             product       rank     result
id id_age                                 
1  30      [A, B, C]  [1, 2, 3]  [x, y, z]
2  23      [A, B, C]  [3, 1, 2]  [p, q, r]
3  29         [A, B]     [2, 1]     [s, t]
```

Comment: For me, that raises an value error: ValueError: No objects to concatenate. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: What is your pandas version? This working in `pandas 0.21.0`

Comment: I have 0.19.2. I will update and try your suggested solution again, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately `agg(list)` is not implemented - it raise `error`

Answer (score 0):

I used do not know how to do it either...

```
df1=df.groupby(['id','id_age'])['product','rank','result'].apply(lambda x : x.T.values.tolist()).apply(pd.Series)
df1.columns=['product','rank','result']
df1
Out[126]: 
             product       rank     result
id id_age                                 
1  30      [A, B, C]  [1, 2, 3]  [x, y, z]
2  23      [A, B, C]  [3, 1, 2]  [p, q, r]
3  29         [A, B]     [2, 1]     [s, t]
```